# How to wrap pixel data for use with glDrawPixels() or textures

Tags: java, opengl, format, pixel

I am trying to render a simple jpg image using JOGL.  However, I'm not sure how to wrap the pixel array data so that glDrawPixels will accept it.  Here's the relevant pieces I have so far:

```
//In Main() Method
private static float[] pixels = {
    0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
    1.f, 0.f, 1.f,
    0.f, 1.f, 0.f
};

//In Render() Method
gl.glRasterPos3f(12.0f, 12.0f, 5.0f);
gl.glDrawPixels(3, 3, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

Eclipse tells me that glDrawPixels takes in a buffer and not a float array, so I guess I need to throw the pixels into a buffer first and specify the buffer, but I'm not sure how to do this, or which buffer to use.  Do I need to use glPixelStore*()?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

--Edit--

I tried to throw the information into a FloatBuffer and the method accepted it, but nothing shows up on the screen.  Am I wrapping the array into a buffer correctly, or is the issue with my calls to the gl functions?  Here's the updated code:

```
private static float[] pixels = {
    0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
    1.f, 0.f, 1.f,
    0.f, 1.f, 0.f
};

static FloatBuffer buf; 

//In Main() Method
buf.wrap(pixels);

//In Render() method
gl.glRasterPos3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gl.glPixelZoom(50.0f, 50.0f);
gl.glDrawPixels(3, 3, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_FLOAT, buf);
```

When I run the program, it just shows a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer Eclipse is talking about is nothing OpenGL specific (per se). The OpenGL functions expect a pointer to the memory locations where to find the data. Java doesn't have pointers, so you need a Java buffer object (not to confuse with a OpenGL buffer object) that provides some way to extract a pointer that can be passed to OpenGL. For example a Java [`FloatBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html). You can pass an instance of that to the OpenGL `gl…Pointer` functions as data parameter then.

Comment: Thank you Datenwolf, using the FloatBuffer I was able to get the command to accept the data, but I'm still having difficulty getting the image to show up.  I have put the updated code into my edits.

Comment: @AlexBarry: You tell OpenGL that each pixel consists of a 4 (RGBA) components, and the image was 3×3 pixels in size. So you'd have to supply 3·3·4 = 36 floating point values in total. Your buffer has only 9 values. You see the problem? BTW: You shouldn't use glDrawPixels. Create a texture and draw a textured quad. glDrawPixels is slow, poorly supported in the drivers (i.e. slow and/or buggy) and has been removed from modern OpenGL versions.